# HQL Join: Retrieve Object based on 2 joins (Path expected for join!)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, join

I am trying to join across 3 objects and running into an issue.  Here is the idea.  In Java I am trying to get a list of a certain object:

```
List<TypeX> typeXList =
    session.createQuery(
        "from X as x " +
        "join Y as y " +
        "where y.z in (:zList)")
    .setParameterList(":zList", zList)
    .list();
```

The zlist is small and dynamically generated in code, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Now I get this error:

```
ERROR 23-05 11:06:41,566 -Servlet.service() for servlet myServlet threw exception
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from X as x join Y as y where y.z in (:zList)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:258)
```

However I think these are mapped, in my xml config I have

```
<class name="X" table="x">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="yId" column="y_id"/>
    <many-to-one name="y" column="y_id"
        insert="false" update="false" class="Y" lazy="proxy"/>
    <!-- I need both of these for other reasons, existing code etc -->
    ...
</class>
```

Now for class Y

```
<class name="Y" table="y">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="z" column="z_id" class="Z" lazy="false"/>
    ...
</class>
```

And Z

```
<class name="Z" table="z">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id" column="z_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    ...
</class>
```

I thought these would be enough to retrieve X'es based on the list of Z's.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be `join X.y where`

Comment: It really is y.z, there are 2 joins involved here in this case one from an object that represents a vote (x), the thing voted on (y) and then the supplier of y (z).  Think about a product rating on amazon, X = the star rating object, Y = the product being rated, Z = the supplier of the product.  In this case we are tryin to get all votes for a list of suppliers.

Comment: @DavidWilliams [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/HSQLJoinTwoClasses.htm) you have an example how to jin 2 column (ojects) in HQL

Comment: Then @Jens, I think I have al of those required setting in the XML above.  Is that not correct?

Comment: @DavidWilliams you wrote `join Y as y ` i think it is wrong and if i understand the example correct, it must be `join x.y`

Comment: Awesome, that did it, thanks, in this case I put it all in the where `where x.y.z in (:zs)`